# Python Tweepy API

Tags: python, twitter, mocking, tweepy

I just start to make an application using Tweepy to communicate with Twitter API.

I want to mock the Tweepy API to test my application and avoid a `RaiseLimitError`.

I found this : https://code.google.com/p/hailbot/source/browse/external/tweepy/tweepybot.py.
But it doesn't work and it hasn't been updated since 2011.

Do you know someting to mock the API?

Comment: Why not just use [`mock`](http://mock.readthedocs.org)?

Comment: Don't want to reinvent the wheel if something already exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's python `mock`

`pip install mock`

Or `caliendo` (a buzzfeed skunkswork project) offers some easy-to-use caching for services.

`pip install caliendo`

There is a lot of good documentation on both.

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/

or

http://www.github.com/buzzfeed/caliendo

```
from caliendo.patch import patch
from caliendo import expected_value

class TestTweepyApi(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('tweepy.api.update_status')
    def test_tweet(self):
        expected_value.is_equal_to(my_method_that_calls_tweepy_update_status())
```

Comment: Calienda looks like interesting. Thanks for you answer. At this time, I use a Mock